# Find complex number $K=\frac{\sqrt{1+z^2} + iz}{z - i\sqrt{1+z^2}}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Can anybody help me with the answer of this question?
 $$K=\frac{\sqrt{1+z^2} + iz}{z - i\sqrt{1+z^2}}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$-i(\sqrt{1+z^2}+iz)=z - i\sqrt{1+z^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Multiplying numerator and denominator by $$z+i\sqrt{z^2+1}$$
this gives $$\frac{z\sqrt{1+z^2}+iz^2+i\sqrt{1+z^2}-z\sqrt{1+z^2}}{z^2+1+z^2}$$